# Which one is camel case

Tags: java

I had a discussion on CamelCase

i believe "camelCaseWord" and "CamelCaseWord" both are in camel case, can any one confirm.

the difference between both the words are first on starts with a lower-Case letter and the second one starts with upper-Case

thanks in advance

Comment: I would describe the first as "lower camel case" and the second as "upper camel case".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO isn't a dictionary.

Comment: A camel has humps in the middle ... not at the ends.

Comment: Both are. The first one is an example of lowerCamelCase, while the second one is written in UpperCamelCase.

Comment: camelCase vs PascalCase.

Comment: @Danstahr: then again "dromedaryCase" sounds kind of weird ...

Comment: @Jongware and would only allow for two-word compounds, you'd need `bactrianCamelCase` for three words, and `AliceTheCamelCase` for more than three... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First line of [the first search hit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) :

> Camel case may start with a capital or, especially in programming languages, with a lowercase letter

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

"Although the first letter of a camel case compound word may or may not be capitalized, the term camel case generally implies lowercase first letter."

So **both** are CamelCase. You can call them "Lower Camel Case" and "Upper Camel Case".

Comment: I didn't. We just had the same answer at the same time :)